# Cannot connect to Postgres deployed to Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am stuck trying to debug a connection issue with PostgreSQL deployed with minikube. I've tried creating the `postgres-service` with both type `NodePort` and `LoadBalancer` but I cannot seem to connect with psql from my localhost.

I've copied in all the config (apologies), as I'm sure there's probably just a silly mistake somewhere!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-credentials
type: Opaque
data:
  user: YWRtaW4=
  password: YWRtaW4=
  database: YWRtaW4=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  volumeName: postgres-pv
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /data/postgres-pv-local
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: postgres-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: postgres-container
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres-container
          image: mdillon/postgis:10
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: user

            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: password

            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: database

          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-volume-mount
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-volume-mount
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: postgres-container
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

Trying to connect on my localhost:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          30h
postgres-service   NodePort    10.105.42.187   <none>        5432:32252/TCP   7m32s

$ export PGPASSWORD=admin
$ psql -h localhost -U admin -p 32252 admin
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
```

I've also tried creating a Ubuntu deployment in the cluster, using `kubectl run -i --tty --attach --image=ubuntu -- bash`, installing psql and connecting on 5432/32252, localhost/postgres-service, etc... but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

Minikube run in a VM. In here, `psql -h localhost -U admin -p 32252 admin` you are trying to connect to postgres that is exposed in `localhost`. But it is not exposed in the `localhost`. Since you defined `NodePort` type service, you can access it using Node ip. So, instead of using `localhost`, try Minikube ip.

```
 $ minikube ip
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and for clarifying that. The issue was caused by a mismatch in labels (see my answer). Cheers

Comment: This is probably the best answer, but I need to elaborate for future reference. If you are on a mac and running minikube on top of docker, this will not work. minikube can't get an IP other than 127.0.0.1 on docker. Use with ``--vm-driver hyperkit`` and ``minikube tunnel`` this will give you an usable and accessible ip

Answer (score 0):

The cause turned out to be a mismatch in label key in the service selector, `app: postgres-container`, and the deployment label, `name: postgres-container`.

Now I can connect, using the `minikube ip` for NodePort:

```
$ export PGPASSWORD=admin
$ psql -h 192.168.99.100 -U admin -p 30917 admin
```

or `localhost` when the service is type LoadBalancer.

Comment: Super newbie here, what was the mismatch about? The spelling seems the same. Asking because I might have the same problem.

Comment: It was because the label in the Deployment config (spec -> template -> metadata -> labels) had 'name' as the key, i.e. `name: postgres-container`, whereas the selector in the Service config (spec -> selector) was selecting on `app: postgres-container`. I just needed to change the selector to `name: postgres-container`. Hope that helps solve your problem!